# SQL combining LIKE and AND gives me wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%whatever%' AND id='1' OR id='2' OR id='3'
```

When using the code above, I get back three rows and not the one with
`column LIKE '%whatever%'`
I find it strange, and can not understand why.

How could I rewrite my sql code to use LIKE to check in sevral rows that have id='whatever'

I use MYSQL and MyISAM

Comment: Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: algebra. algebra. boolean algebra. 1 + 2 * 3 = 7 not 9

Comment: *I use MYSQL and MyISAM PROBLEM SOLVED* Uh no, that combination creates a problem.

Comment: Please do not add `solved` to the question. Instead, accept an answer or post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 6):

You need parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%whatever%' AND (id='1' OR id='2' OR id='3')
```

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`, so your original was interpreted as:

```
WHERE )column LIKE '%whatever%' AND id='1') OR id='2' OR id='3'
```

The original is better written with `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%whatever%' AND id in ('1', '2', '3')
```

And, if `id` is really an integer, you should drop the single quotes.  They suggest the type is really a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IN` function

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%whatever%' AND id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

I assume id is a varchar. If its an int then use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%whatever%' AND id IN (1, 2, 3)
```